# PHP Fuel SDK - Sending TriggeredSend Asynchronously

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, php, fuel-sdk, asynchronous

It does not appear that I can send an [asynchronous TriggeredSend call](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/soap-api/creating-a-triggered-send-using-the-async-api.html) to the system with the PHP SDK. Am I missing something? I can add Priority to the `props` which gets attached to the TriggeredSendDefinition object, but I can't seem to create a true Options object with the Fuel API. Can this only be done via the older SOAP API?

```
$myclient           = new ET_Client(true, true);
$sendTrigger        = new ET_TriggeredSend();
$sendTrigger->props = ['CustomerKey' => 'myTriggeredSend', 'Priority' => 'High'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FuelSDK for PHP does not support asynchronous requests.  This is not a limitation of the SDK, but instead a limitation of the SOAP services that the SDK utilizes not supporting token authentication.  Username/Password authentication with SOAP is required for asynchronous.

Asynchronous is not the same as Priority sending.  Priority sending is a setting that exists on the Triggered Email definition(It has to be updated on the TriggeredSendDefinition, not passed at send time in the API request).  Priority affects how it is processed regardless of how the request comes in. Priority sending can be used with the FuelSDK.  Priority is an additional feature which may not be enabled in the account.

See the Priority section at:
http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/triggered_emails/triggered_emails_guide/

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if the older SOAP classes from the [API Starter Kit](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/api_starter_kits/) are deprecated? It looks like they have what's needed for async calls.

Comment: The API Starter Kit is a collection code samples that use PHP standard SOAPClient class (along with soap-wsse.php and xmlseclibs.php for authentication).  That method for accessing the SOAP service is still valid and would provide more flexibility by accessing the SOAP services more directly compared with the SDK.  Additional examples can be found at: https://github.com/MichaelAllenClark/exacttarget-soap-php